# Can't attach volume to docker with jenkins through fig

Tags: jenkins, docker, fig

I try setup sonarqube and jenkins through one fig config. But can't attach volume to docker with jenkins through. Can somebody help?

In this way container run correctly:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /opt/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home shami13fastpool/fastpool-jenkins
```

fig.yml:

```
postgresql:
  image: orchardup/postgresql:latest
  environment:
    - POSTGRESQL_USER=sonar
    - POSTGRESQL_PASS=sonar
    - POSTGRESQL_DB=sonar
  volumes:
    - /opt/db/sonarqube/:/var/lib/postgresql
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
sonarqube:
  image: harbur/sonarqube:latest
  links:
    - postgresql:db
  environment:
    - DB_USER=sonar
    - DB_PASS=sonar
    - DB_NAME=sonar
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
    - "443"
jenkins:
  image: shami13fastpool/fastpool-jenkins:latest
  volumes:
    - /opt/jenkins_home/:/var/jenkins_home/:rw
  links:
    - postgresql:db
    - sonarqube:sonarqube
 ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

This both commands must run the same instance of jenkins, but i've got different instances

Comment: Do you get some error? Or what is the problem?

Comment: I don't get error. I just see that I have different instances of jenkins by "fig up" and "docker run command"

Comment: You get a new container every time you run `docker run` or `fig up`, that is expected. Is that what you mean by "instance"?

Comment: I mean that in /opt/jenkins_home/ i have set of settings for jenkins, and in docker run, it's use this config, in fig not

Answer (score 0):

In your `fig.yml` file, you're linking to postgres and sonarqube, but you're not doing any linking in your Docker command.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but when i comment this linking and sonarqube with db, have the same result